# Vlan not connected to one network virtual machine to another network virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vlan

I created two ubuntu vm and I installed dhcp server on both the vm's. I configured the interfaces file and geting the ip address for vm1:10.192.1.2 and vm2:10.192.2.3

I have 24ports Switch. Now I want to create a common vlan id to both the vm's.

I want to communicate this two vm's using same Vlan id

How can I do it simply ?

Comment: Trunk port and set up the vlan on the host/sdn etc.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the fact that VLAN is port-depended not ip-related, the 2 VM's are on the same vlan by default(if they use the same host). The thing that prevents them from pinging each other, is the different subnet of the two, if they're both on /24 subnet masks. You can change you're IP adds or subnet masks the way they can see each other, therefore communicate.